# Is copying Stack Overflow content to own blog and linking it in an answer appropriate behavior?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer, attribution, copycat-sites

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39179896/3636601) someone has copied the question to his blog and linked the blog there. Is it OK to do it, or should the link be deleted? In the blog there is nothing more than in the answer.

And there are a some more answers where the blog is linked

---

*Screenshot of original (and now deleted) answer:*

[image]

---

And the blog entry, where you can see that the answer is the same as on stackoverflow with no more explantion:

[image]

Comment: copy is one thing. but link it from stackoverflow to the external site is an other thing

Comment: Lol, that entire blog is a copy&pasted jumble of other people's work. Seems to be a popular thing in South Asia right now (at least that's the only place where I've seen this), presumably to show off technical knowledge. I wonder if they manage to fool anybody

Comment: As an extra slap in the face to visitors, the blog's navbar uses red text on a green background. Which ranges from difficult to impossible to read, depending on your genes. I also like how "About" links to `about:blank`. I mean, I guess that's clever. I don't think you have to read the content to determine their technical knowledge...

Comment: Every answer I can find by that user is code-only with a link to a brand new blog post copying the question. Are we sure this is a real person and not a bot or spam network?

Comment: @ssube Yes i think so, Do have seen a bot who has answered a question

Comment: @Jens I can't say I have ever seen that, but it could simply be human spammers trying to create a highly-linked blog and draw traffic.

Comment: @Pekka 웃: Sure they do - people who are stupid enough to do that are stupid enough to fall for it. (You would expect them to see through it, but nope.)

Comment: Worth noting he has multiple blogs, this is another one from the same user: http://mission10xproject.blogspot.be.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> ### Can I do anything myself?
>
> Absolutely! While larger cases of mass violations will require the Stack Exchange team's intervention, smaller cases where a user simply wasn't aware of our attribution requirements do not require us to get involved. If you see a blog post which copied our content and it's just a one-off deal, you should feel free to contact the author as a concerned member of the community. There is nothing wrong with a user pointing out the rules and hopefully getting an author to fix their content as well as educating them about our attribution requirements.

In other words, you can contact the author of that blog to tell him that they can't copy Stack Overflow content without proper attribution, but I don't think it's worth contacting Stack Exchange team.

As for linking to his blog from Stack Overflow answer: that link doesn't add anything to that answer, so I edited it out.

Comment: I would also like to suggest that if you find a trend of these (like the user in question has), it may be worth looking deeper and maybe flagging, in case you've stumbled across a sock puppet or spam ring.

Answer (score 7):

**Legal stuff:**

- CC-BY-SA is  neither exclusive nor does it involve transfer of ownership. That means you can put all your own contributions on Stack Overflow always also on your blog at any time and without any attribution necessary. Nothing anyone else can or should do about it.
- CC-BY-SA permits republishing if attribution is given. That means you can publish all of the content under CC-BY-SA on your blog at any time with proper attribution. Nothing anyone else can or should do about it.

In this case, the answerer can surely put his answer on his blog but must give proper attribution when also putting the question there. If he does, the blog is safe.

**Link spamming stuff:**

- Links in answers must be helpful (they must provide additional information)
- Links to own resources can be partly regarded as self promotional. As such there are additional limits like disclosing the affiliation and in general not overdoing it or people may start downvoting or flagging (see [Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)).

In this case, the answerer did not post a helpful link (can be deleted) and additionally did not disclose his affiliation with the link and in general I would see the repeated linking to his blog as overly self-promotional. A mod should tell him to reduce the promotion of his blog to where it actually makes sense (like in the scenario of [Boris Stitnicky](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333525/1536976) where real additional, useful information is linked and the answer can stand on its own nevertheless).

There is a bit of a grey zone between useful additional information and spamming/self promotion while if you link to somewhere else we always assume you make it only because you deem the link to be important for the answer.

Comment: That SO uses CC-BY-SA is irrelevant for the first point: I can always reproduce *my content* elsewhere, independent of the license. The only exception would be when posting involves a transfer of ownership.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Transfer of ownership are exactly the cases I thought about. For example try writing a book and selling through a publisher and then also offering the content for free. This will not work if you licensed your work exclusively to the publisher. CC-BY-SA means you don't license the content exclusively to SO.

Comment: Some open-source projects require contributors to [assign copyright ownership of their contribution to the project, for various reasons](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/185729/is-it-fair-to-require-copyright-assignments-from-contributors-of-an-os-project).  The terms of the copyright assignment dictate whether you can still use your code however you want (e.g. releasing it yourself under a different licence).  So the CC-BY-SA or GPL or whatever is irrelevant, as they don't cover this part.

Comment: To state it another way, you could have a transfer agreement that *did* prevent you from republishing your own work, except in compliance with a copyleft license.  But that's not what's going on here, so the license doesn't matter, only the (lack of) any kind of copyright assignment or transfer.

Comment: @PeterCordes The CC-BY-SA is relevant as it's the license SO uses. I changed the text from "under this license" to "only under this license" to avoid the cases you mention. Of course you are right but I don't see how this was the case here for the guy in question. He very probably never contributed to any other open source content, gave the copyright away and put that content also on SO. Regarding the legal stuff - I don't want do discuss it exhaustively here, just mention a few cases I deem relevant.

Comment: Mark and I are both arguing that your first bullet point makes no sense: "*CC-BY-SA is a copyleft license. That means [...you can republish your own work under any other license you want...]*".  But that's *not* what that means, and not why that's true.  I agree it's pretty much irrelevant to point of your answer, or this question, and is just nit-picking.  Still, incorrect statements should be fixed, IMO.  Releasing a copy of your work on SO under the CC-BY-SA has nothing to do with still being free to release your own work on your own blog under any license you want.

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay, I messed up the meaning of copyleft. Thanks for pointing that out. What I wanted to say was, that "CC-BY-SA is neither exclusive nor does it involve transfer of ownership." which is the point I wanted to make. I hope it's better that way.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that clickbaiting shown in OP is a bad practice, but in general, the author should be free to factor out smaller or larger part of an extensive answer to their own website, if they do it in good will. The remaining text on SO should still form a standalone, if shorter, answer to the question; it should not turn into a link-only answer. But this does not apply to merely scraping or ripping SO content away so as to gain content for private sites, as is the case with the user in question. I turned this [into a separate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333614/is-it-all-right-to-factor-out-so-content-to-private-websites) because the general discussion does not belong under this particular case.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding anything to disagree with here.

Comment: OK maybe "most significant contributor" is a little iffy, particularly in the case of community wiki answers, or answers that have been so heavily edited by users other than the author that you can't really say that the writing was contributed by the author anymore. But if it's entirely or almost entirely the original work of the author? They still have every right to their own content - they can repost it on their own website and they can edit their answer here however they see fit so long as they don't outright vandalize it (i.e. so long as "they do it in good will").

Comment: This is clickbaiting, the user in person actually lures people to his site to receive income by google ads (when checking adblocker). Disgusting.

Comment: @Roberrrt: I think you meant to post your comment under the question, not this answer.

Comment: Not quite, but I should be more specific.

Boris Stitnicky writes * if they do it in good will.* inside his answer, this clearly isn't a sign of good will. And in this case, related to the example given by OP, the user should be reprimanded.

After re-reading the answer here, I suppose Boris (kinda) has the same idea about this. But the usage of words is a bit off.

Comment: @Roberrrt: Would it help if Boris posted this under a separate question that wasn't about someone obviously doing it in bad faith?

Comment: Exactly. I'm agreeing with his point, just the idea of justifying this action with the example of clickbaiting is something I despise. But then again, Boris has the same idea about it I think.

Comment: @Roberrrt: Fair enough, I guess the sheer number of downvotes on this answer made me think you were speaking on behalf of the downvoters.

Comment: @BoltClock I suppose the people who downvote didn't read the his response through, and assumed he was blatantly stating this behaviour is right (in this case). Perhaps as suggestion: edit the answer to state your idea about the current example?

Comment: @BoltClock Cheers for the edit, +1'd

Comment: Turning your own answer into a blog post is totally ok. Copying other people's questions without attribution is the problem here, AFAIK.

Comment: This, in addition to the 'read more about this on my blog'
He should just reply the entire answer on the question, and 'might' post a link to the blogpost with the entire question-answer sequence.

Comment: I don't think we should police how much content a user has on their own blog versus as an answer they provide. If their answer is complete and useful, however minimal, they should be able to point to their own blog with elaborations as they see fit. Key is 'complete and useful' by itself, otherwise it becomes a link-only answer. The fact that a user benefits in other ways than reputation shouldn't be a concern of ours.

Comment: @BoltClock: I made a separate post about the general principle.

Comment: Apparently posting separately didn't help at all.