# Is it all right to factor out SO content to private websites?

Tags: discussion, answers, attribution, copycat-sites

Recently, an example of a [bad will edit that moved content out of SO to a private blog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333388/is-copying-stack-overflow-content-to-own-blog-and-linking-it-in-an-answer-approp/333525?noredirect=1#comment389801_333525) has appeared.

However, I believe (and other people agree) that the author of an answer should be free to factor out smaller or larger part of an extensive answer to their own website. I am posting this as a separate question: What should be the general rule in these cases?

Comment: As long as you provide a proper attribution, you can use SO content on a private website.

Comment: @Gothdo: Agreed, as long as the content _stays_ on SO.

Comment: What is a private website? We can't control what is copied to intranets and local running stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, it's ***not*** okay to move* (part of) the answer to your own blog.

A SO answer should answer the question, even if *all the links* in there suddenly died.

Linking to your own blog, saying *"For complete Description visit my blog..."* is just advertising. Personally, I'd have flagged that as spam, weren't it for the fact he wrote *"**my** blog"*.

<sub>*: With *"move"*, I mean **removing** the content from SO. Copying your own content to your own blog is fine.</sub>

Comment: I semi-agree. While I think one has to answer the question entirely on StackOverflow, he or she should have the choice to copy back _**his own content**_ with proper attribution on his own blog. The linked example didn't specify this though.

Comment: _"He or she should have the choice to copy back his own content "_ Agreed, as long as he doesn't remove it from SO, then. If you _do_ remove it from SO, you're just clickbaiting.

Comment: Ah, in that case, our opinions are aligned.

Comment: @Roberrrt: I added a small explanation

Comment: I don't think that's what the question was talking about? I think it was just asking if you could post content on your on site that you posted on SO.

Comment: @hichris123 _"should be free to factor out smaller or larger part of an extensive answer to their own website"_: I interpret that as witholding a part of the answer in order to lure a user looking for an answer, to your own site.

Comment: I think the "factor out" part is unclear, we'll have to see what was intended by that.

Comment: I don't think it means "copy", though.

Comment: There is a fine line IMO between distilling an on-site answer, often a long-winded or excessively detailed one, to the essentials, and outright stripping it of its content. The latter is vandalism. The former, when it's clear that the author isn't acting in bad faith, is not. I think it is best to treat such answers on a case-by-case basis. The "For complete Description visit my blog" sounds super pretentious for its awkward wording but even high-profile users like Eric Lippert have said similar lines in their earliest answers, just much more eloquently.

Comment: I'm not sure if Eric does that anymore, but it does get a bit annoying to come across an old answer of his that basically says "I [blogged] on this subject last week."

Comment: There's a fine line between click-baiting and making the example simpler. One reason not to post the same content on an SO answer as one post on one's personal blog, is to get views on the blog. Another is that the full explanation is simply too long for an SO answer. The first reason could be considered "spam". The latter one _may_ indicate the question is too broad. But I agree: _"treat such answers on a case-by-case basis."_

Comment: I agree. Well, if the question is too broad, nobody should be complaining that they're moving the answer out of Stack Overflow where the question doesn't belong to begin with :^)